# How to remove special character from a string in input on onkeyup event

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to remove special character like @,#, etc. except space with null string

```html
<input type='text' onkeyup="this.value.replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/g', '')">
```

But it's not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove `quotes` around regex pattern and also assign replaced value to `this.value` because replace method creates a new string, it doesn't modify the string you're operating on

```html
<input type='text' onkeyup="this.value = this.value.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/g, '')">
```

Comment: Yes it's working thank you

Answer (score 0):

Changing the value that way doesn't replace the original value. It gives you a new string instead. Once you do the replacement, you have to assign it back to `this.value` and that should do the trick.

Also, regex pattern doesn't need to be in quotes. It starts and ends with '/'. So you have to remove that.

More Read - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace

```html
<input type='text' onkeyup="this.value = this.value.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/g,'')">
```

### Suggestion

The inline event listeners are considered bad practice and you should probably do it in the JS land using `addEventListener`.

Answer (score 0):

It's generally [not a good idea](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events) to use inline event handlers. Alternative: use the `input` event and a delegated handler for it:

```js
{
  document.addEventListener("input", textOnly, true);
  
  function textOnly(evt) {
    const origin = evt.target;
    if (origin.id === "textOnly") {
      origin.value = origin.value
        .replace(/[^a-z0-9]$/i, "");
      //                   ^ only the last inputted character
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="textOnly">
```